# AccessViolationException when playing audio in vb

Tags: vb.net, audio

I'm trying to write a clone of frogger for a project and decided to go above and beyond and add sounds.  Well after coding for the audio I went to play the game and it breaks and gives me an AccessViolationException.  I set the resources to public to be safe and still breaks.

The actual code i have is

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.dp_frogger_hop, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

Answer (score 0):

iirc you should have a file-extension to your file, is that a var-name or the filename ? What happens if you just open from e.g. C:\temp\ ?

Comment: to what i understand a file extension isn't needed if its an resource loaded into the project folder.  As to your second bit I don't understand the question but I'd guess var-name because its a resource not a direct file.

Comment: What i meant is that you try it without having it in your ressources. Instead you can execute it from a folder on your local drive.

Comment: I tried running the code with a direct path instead of using the resources.  It doesn't crash but it doesn't play the sound

Comment: Dumb it down then, try  My.Computer.Audio.Play("C:\windows\media\Windows Navigation Start.wav")    If this is not working, you have an issue with wav-playback. Playing the file mntioned above works for me. If it does work, your file might be screwed.